# Progress Dialog Shows but no Progress Bar Shows and Message Isn't Updating

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have this class that gets called from a fragment. On progress update gets called but the message will not update. I also am not seeing any progress bar or spinner. Just the title and the message, seen some similar problems but nothing where the progress bar isn't showing at all. Also, my message will not update at all in onProgressUpdate but printing out the values does show that it increments inside of the onProgressUpdate.

Edit: Here is how I start the task

```
DownloadFilesTask download = new DownloadFilesTask();
download.execute(urls.toArray(new String[urls.size()]));
```

Here is the class

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Downloading","Downloaded 0/"+urls.size(), false);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.setMax(urls.size());
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String[] urls) {
    int count = urls.length;
    long totalSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //Do things in background here
            publishProgress(new Integer[] {i});
    }
    return totalSize;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... progress) {
    System.out.println(progress[0]); //This does print correctly
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloaded "+ progress[0] +"/"+urls.size());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
}
```

}

Comment: How did you start the task,please show the code.

Comment: Edited it to show the way I start it, its just the generic way you start a task so that is why I didn't include it. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the way your ProgressDialog is initialized.

Replace your onPreExecute with this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Downloaded 0/" + urls.size());
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.setMax(urls.size());
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Essentially, you need to call `setProgressStyle` before calling show.

Additionally, you can remove the `runOnUiThread` code in `onProgressUpdate` because `onProgressUpdate` is invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Wow, such a simple issue. Thank you very much, will award bounty when I can ~22 hrs left

Comment: Glad to help - it is a tricky bug. If you're interested, take a look at the ProgressDialog source - you'll see why you were running into this issue. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ProgressDialog.java#L324

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact cause, but it is not required to `setProgress` on `runnable` as `onProgressUpdate` will run on UI thread.

Try Replacing

`getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloaded "+ progress[0] +"/"+urls.size());
        } 
    });`

with

`progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Downloaded "+ progress[0] +"/"+urls.size());`

Also - Are you doing networking stuff in `doInbackground()`, else we cannot see progress which will be dismissed on `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I actually had that before but it wasn't working so I decided to try the runonuithread. I am downloading images so yes it does take a while. The dialog shows but there is no progress bar in it, just the title. Once it is finished downloading the images it closes just fine

Comment: Ok. May be try initialising the progress dialog first and call the `show()` later at the end of `onPreExecute()`